# Selenium Test .net core 3.1 on Release Pipeline has framework Mismatch

Tags: selenium, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple selenium test on .net core 3.1 with selenium.webdriver.
[image: Selenium test]

I build it on the build pipelines with yaml that does Restore > publish > publish artifact. The Dlls look fine.
I put this into a release pipeline and I keep getting:
[image: Error]

My pipeline tasks are a Pipeline Platform installer running the Latest and a VSTest task that runs the "Installed by tooler".
My Agent is Azure pipelines with windows-2019. Not sure what I am missing here. I cant run this simple test. Thanks

Comment: the wonderful world of .net terminology... Basically ASP.NET-Core should include/support most/all the functions for different .net framework versions.   These messages probably aren't the problem.  Try/catch your driver calls to see if any Selenium specific exceptions are thrown.  Moving the window position to 2000, 100 is a little odd.  Any reason for that?

Comment: It was arbitrary position. The selenium tests are passing. Its not running on the Release Pipeline it doesnt run the test. I will try to downgrade to see if i can get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using VStest task to run dotnet-core-3.1 tests. You need to specify the `framework option` to `.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1` in the `Other console options` field: See below:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*Test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    otherConsoleOptions: '/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1"'
```

[image]

You can also use [dotnet test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) in the release pipeline to run the tests on .net core 3.1.

Comment: You can use the dotnet test task in the release pipeline but it wont work since it the test command implicitly does a restore, build and test. Even if you put arguments not to build or restore, it wont pick up the tests in the dlls.

Comment: You also can't even declare test reruns with the dotnet test task. Barely usable if you have any flakey tests!